# Вибрация во всю продолжительность звукового оповещения

Tags: android, android-notification

Настройки приложения реализованы через PreferenceActivity, где пользователь может настроить режим оповещения (выбор мелодии, вибрация). Сложность у меня возникла с тем, чтобы реализовать вибрацию все время, пока звучит мелодия.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText(title);
        builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(color));
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_white_48dp);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String soundUri = sharedPreferences.getString("notification_sound_key", "content://settings/system/notification_sound");
        if (soundUri.length() != 0) {
            builder.setSound(Uri.parse(soundUri));
        }
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkBoxLED", true)) {
            builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 5000);
        }
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkBoxVibrate", true)) {
            long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000, 2000};
            builder.setVibrate(pattern);
        }



        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) timeStamp, notification);
```